# insert sub string to another string

Tags: c++, string

I have the next strings:

```
string str1 = "1,123456,name1,4";
string str2;
```

I want to insert to str2, the string of str1 (from the 9th letter till the `,`).

so str2 should be: `name1`

if `str1 = "2,234567,namenamename,5"`, so `str2` will be: `namenamename` (again: from the 9th letter till the `,`).

I don't want to use `strtok`.

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `std::string::find()` in combination with `std::string::substr()`:

```
std::string::size_type pos = 9;
std::string str1 = "1,123456,name1,4";
std::string::size_type commaPos = str1.find(',', pos);
if (commaPos == std::string::npos)
{
    commaPos = str1.length();
}

std::string str2 = str1.substr(pos, commaPos - pos);
```

Here is a [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/48Ihhx%2459).